# 13.10 installation desktop

Tags: unity, 13.10

I have been away from Ubuntu for a while which may explain my problem. I installed 13.10 and seem to be missing the Unity utility as nothing will appear on my desktop.

I am probably missing a simple fix, if so could someone point it out?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd try.

Ensure Unity is installed:

`sudo apt-get install unity`

and reconfigure your entire system:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`

(that last command will likely take a long time)

Answer (score 0):

In the login screen choose **"Guest login"**. After you login, the icons and the everything else is there. Now from the top right corner in the system menu select **"Log Out..."** and you are back to the login screen. Login in your user.

Everything should be back again.